# How to even approach this type of question

Tags: time, declination, right-ascension

[image]

Can someone tell me how one would approach this type of question. is there an equation we would use or something of the sort.

Ths solution to this question is given below but I just want to understand how it works.
https://www.ioaastrophysics.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/TH-solution-2017.pdf

Inparticular I dont understand these 2 equations. [image]

Comment: You should give some context and what you know how to do.  This questuon seems to be about the relationship between Sidereal Time and UTC.

Comment: Is there enough information here to answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culmination

Comment: yes the question contains enough information to be answered I will link the solution here. Its not the solution Im confused about but its how its solved.
https://www.ioaastrophysics.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/TH-solution-2017.pdf

Comment: the question is from the IOAA 2017. I'm confused about how you can get the date for culmination at 9 am. time for culmination changes everyday because the sidereal day runs about 4 minutes faster but other than that I dont understand how you would get from the information given to a specific date.

Comment: Sounds like you know enough to answer it yourself.  What time will it culminate on Jan 1, then compute how many 4 minute intervals you need before it culminates at 9.

Comment: Why do you want 9 AM? The question specifies 9 PM.

Comment: yeah no I mistakenly wrote 9 AM I meant 9 PM

Comment: Ok Ill try it using greg millers approach